# Is there a way of changing the colour of the area under the curve of a kernal density estimate on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

N = 10000
totalinc_02 <- rnorm(N)
totalinc_04 <- rnorm(N)

remained_agri <- rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.05)
reallocated_manu <- rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.05)

inc0204_p_agri <- data.frame(totalinc_02 , totalinc_04 , remained_agri, reallocated_manu)
```

I have made two kernal density plots as follows:

```
ggplot(inc0204_p_agri, aes(log(totalinc_02), fill = factor(remained_agri))) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "(log) Annual Income in 2001",
       y = "Density") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="",
                         breaks=c("1", "0"),
                         labels=c("Will not reallocate", "Will reallocate"))

ggplot(inc0204_p_agri, aes(log(totalinc_04), fill = factor(reallocated_manu))) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "(log) Annual Income in 2003",
       y = "Density") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="",
                         breaks=c("0", "1"),
                         labels=c("Did not reallocate", "Reallocated"))
```

Producing,

[image]

[image]

Is there a way that I can make the colour under the density curve for those who reallocated in the second plot correspond to the colour of under the density curve for those who will reallocate in the first plot?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to fix this might be to swap into the 2nd plot:

```
ggplot(inc0204_p_agri, 
       aes(log(totalinc_04), 
       fill = factor(reallocated_manu) %>% forcats::fct_rev)) +
```

or this base R equivalent:

```
ggplot(inc0204_p_agri, 
       aes(log(totalinc_04), 
       fill = relevel(factor(reallocated_manu), "1"))) +
```

Either of those will reverse the order of the factors, which is necessary because your breaks are in reversed order between the two plots; "0" is Will Reallocate and "0" is also Did not reallocate. The fill looks like its assigned in order of the underlying factor levels, even though you have manually specified in both cases you want the "Will/did not reallocate" listed first.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

N = 10000
totalinc_02 <- rnorm(N)
totalinc_04 <- rnorm(N)

remained_agri <- rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.05)
reallocated_manu <- rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.05)

inc0204_p_agri <- data.frame(totalinc_02 , totalinc_04 , remained_agri, reallocated_manu)

ggplot(inc0204_p_agri, aes(log(totalinc_02), fill = factor(remained_agri))) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "(log) Annual Income in 2001",
       y = "Density") +
  scale_fill_discrete(type = c("blue", "red"), 
                      name="",
                      breaks=c("1", "0"),
                      labels=c("Will not reallocate", "Will reallocate"))
#> Warning in log(totalinc_02): NaNs produced

#> Warning in log(totalinc_02): NaNs produced
#> Warning: Removed 5022 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(inc0204_p_agri, aes(log(totalinc_04), fill = factor(reallocated_manu))) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "(log) Annual Income in 2003",
       y = "Density") +
  scale_fill_discrete(type = c("green", "blue"),
                      name="",
                      breaks=c("0", "1"),
                      labels=c("Did not reallocate", "Reallocated"))
#> Warning in log(totalinc_04): NaNs produced
#> Warning in log(totalinc_04): NaNs produced
#> Warning: Removed 5021 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>